# "You must come from time" meaning in sci-fi movie "In Time" (2011)

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is a sci-fi movie, read this part to understand:

> [first lines] Will Salas: [voice over] ... We’re genetically
>   engineered to stop ageing at twenty five. The trouble is, we live only
>   one more year, unless we can get more time. Time is now the currency.
>   We earn it and spend it. The rich can live forever and the rest of us?
>   I just wanna wake up with more time on my hand than hours in the day.

Then, quote for my question:

> [at the poker table in a casino]
>
> Philippe Weis: I don’t believe we’ve had the pleasure of your company
>   before, Mr…?
>
> Will Salas: Salas. Will Salas.
>
> Philippe Weis: Philippe Weis. You must come from time.
>
> Will Salas: You could say I’m gambling my inheritance.
>
> Philippe Weis: You don’t have a guard, Mr. Salas?

( http://www.moviequotesandmore.com/in-time-movie-quotes/ )

What does "You must come from time" mean?

Comment: you can download subtitles from http://www.yifysubtitles.com/subtitle/intime20111080p720pblurayx264ytsag-english-95578.zip

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this usage of "time" has relevance only in the context of the 2011 movie "In Time", and should be apparent due to the basic premise of the film.

Comment: @Cascabel i do not see any problem here, nobody says it is of general english. but i being not native speaker could not know it easily, the simple idea to put "money" instead of "time" and google that had not come to my mind.

Comment: The main problem that I had with this question is that you did not even bother to include the explanation that the dialogue came from a sci-fi movie about a dystopic future when "time" substitutes as the global currency. The dialogue is presented here as if it were some type of standard usage, and the link is the only thing providing the actual context.

Comment: @Cascabel i will edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the cited source, time itself is a currency. This means any phrase outside of this premise that mentions currency can have that term replaced with "time" inside this premise. There exist a number of such colloquialisms. A few examples: "you must come from money", "they come from money", and "it must be nice to come from money". These examples suggest that the person started from a richer point than other people, and it is suggested that the person has lived their life taking advantage of that fact. Bastardizing the provided examples with the gimmick of the movie yields this same suggestion, except with "time" as the point of reference: "you must come from time", "they come from time", and "it must be nice to come from time".

Also, the premise of the movie can be summed up after recognizing another colloquialism: "Time is money." Then, the premise of this movie is: "What if time actually was money?"

Comment: a dictionary article about "come from money" : https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come%20from%20money